# Required String parameter is not present error when i upload

Tags: java, spring-boot

i try to upload a MultipartFile with a String param

```
  @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResultHelper uploadHomework(@RequestParam MultipartFile file,
                                       @RequestParam(value="resourceId") String resourceId) {
        return ResultHelper.succeed(iHomeworkService.uploadHomework(file, resourceId));
    }
```

and this happen when i want to upload a 100mb+file
[Required String parameter 'resourceId' is not present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygvd2.png)

Comment: that only happen when i upload big file ,small file upload successfully

Comment: Can you include how you're calling this? From the error – `Required String parameter 'resourceId' is not present` – it looks like you aren't including a required request parameter.

Comment: Also, it's best to avoid posting screenshots of text (error messages, sourcd code, etc), and instead include the text directly in your post.

Comment: ```resourceId: 1466023550434230274 file: (binary)``` , that is my ulpload param.